# Button points to wrong action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller, actiondispatch

I'm having issues getting a button to point to the correct action in my controller.  My show view has the following buttons:

```
<%= button_to "Submit for Approval", {action: "submit", :id => @ecn.id}  %>
<%= button_to "Close ECN", {action: "close", :id => @ecn.id}, :onclick => "return confirm('Once an ECN is closed it can no longer be edited, are you sure you want to close this ECN?')" %>
```

My controller has the following two actions:

```
  def submit

    @ecn = Ecn.find(params[:id])
    @email_list = EmailList.all

    respond_to do |format|
      EcnNotifier.submit_engineering(@ecn).deliver if @ecn.distribute_engineering?
      EcnNotifier.submit_purchasing(@ecn).deliver if @ecn.distribute_purchasing?
      EcnNotifier.submit_manufacturing(@ecn).deliver if @ecn.distribute_manufacturing?
      EcnNotifier.submit_qantel(@ecn).deliver if @ecn.distribute_qantel?
      EcnNotifier.submit_planning(@ecn).deliver if @ecn.distribute_planning?
      format.html { redirect_to ecns_url, alert: "Ecn has been submitted for approval." }
      format.json { render json: @ecns }
    end
  end

  def close
    @ecn = Ecn.find(params[:id])
    @ecn = @ecn.close_status

    respond_to do |format|
      EcnNotifier.close_engineering(@ecn).deliver if @ecn.distribute_engineering?
      format.html { redirect_to ecns_url, alert: "Ecn has been closed.  A confirmation email has been sent to the appropriate personnel." }
      format.json { render json: @ecns }
    end
  end
```

When I click the "Submit for Approval" button, the submit action runs as expected.
When I click the "Close ECN" button, the alert comes up as expected, but then the submit action is processed rather than the close action.  My development log shows the following when I click the "Close ECN" button:

```
    Started POST "/ecns/index?id=34" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-03 11:53:02 -0700
    Processing by EcnsController#submit as HTML
    ...
```

So I can see that it is calling the incorrect action.  I'm not sure what would cause this, I don't know too much about routing, but here is my routes file as well:

```
Engdb::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :email_lists

get 'home' => 'home#index'
get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  get "login/index"

  get "sessions/new"

  get "sessions/create"

  get "sessions/destroy"

  resources :users

  get "home/index"

  resources :ecns

  resources :revisions

  resources :drawings

  resources :home

 match 'ecns/index' => 'ecns#submit'
 match 'ecns/index' => 'ecns#close'
```

I added the two "match" lines when I created the two actions.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your routes for `ecns#submit` and `ecns#close` have identical paths and HTTP verbs.

The way rails handles routes is that it will go from top to bottom in your `routes.rb` and stop when it finds the first path that matches the request. So, a request to `ecns/index` will always get sent to `ecns#submit`. If the path is identical, how would the router known which action to send it to?

Try specifying a different path for `ecns#close`, or specifying different HTTP verbs for each action, such as `post` for `#submit` and `delete` for `#close`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the path in routes for the close action, and ensure you're using the right HTTP verb based on routes (POST vs. PUT most likely):

```
<%= button_to "Close ECN", {:url => <close_path>, :method => <:put/:post>, :id => @ecn.id}, :onclick => "return confirm('Once an ECN is closed it can no longer be edited, are you sure you want to close this ECN?')" %>
```